# wxpython - Post custom event that propagates

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

Right now I have a child panel that post some event. I've tried

```
    myEvent = events.ChangedAvailModelsEvent()
    #self.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(myEvent)
    wx.PostEvent(self, myEvent)
```

I create my event with

```
ChangedAvailModelsEvent, EVT_CHANGEDAVAILMODELS = NewEvent()
```

I bind with

```
self.Bind(events.EVT_CHANGEDAVAILMODELS, self.OnUpdate)
```

which takes place in some nth grandparent. I have print statements telling me the event was processed, but I my function is never called afterwards. I'm not sure what the problem is. I feel like the event is not propagating upwards. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to use `NewCommandEvent` instead of `NewEvent`.  Command events will automatically propagate up the parent chain in search of a handler.  Non-command events will only be processed by the object they are posted to.  See http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind_vs._self.button.Bind.